# Como bloquear data retroativa input DATE?

Tags: javascript, html, data

```
<input id="checkin" name="checkin" class="date-picker form-control" type="date" value="<?php echo $datahoje; ?>">
```

Codigo Javascript

```
    function pad(valor) {
    return valor.toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

function formata(data) {
    return data.getFullYear() + '-' + pad(data.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + pad(data.getDate())
           + 'T' + pad(data.getHours()) + ':' + pad(data.getMinutes());
}

var campo = document.querySelector('#agend');
var hoje = formata(new Date());

// DOMContentLoaded: assim que carregar a página
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // seta a data mínima para o campo
    campo.min = hoje;
});

// mostra mensagem de erro customizada (caso não queira a mensagem padrão do browser)
campo.addEventListener('invalid', function(e) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity(`A data não pode ser anterior a ${hoje}`);
});
campo.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity('');
    e.target.checkValidity();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Codigo PHP:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$datahoje = date('Y-m-d', time());
```

Código HTML:

```
<form>
    <input  min="<?php echo $datahoje; ?>" type="date" id="agend" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Consegui :)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).